# Strategies and indicators in one script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I put the conditional expression of the rsi value in the chart and set ovrylay= true, the strategy and rsi come out together on the chart, making it difficult to see the chart. What function can I use to make the strategy appear above the chart and below the chart for rsi?

Also, even after opening a position, the photo shape is displayed for each condition... How do I make the photo shape appear only once?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is expected isn't it?

The RSI values in your example are around 65-77 and the price is around 17000. How can you show all those levels without messing up your chart's scale? You cannot.

You can add `scale=scale.none` to your `strategy()` call and it will not do any scaling but you won't see the RSI lines nice and clean.

You can also have a look at [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another) faq question to see how you can rescale an indicator from one scale to another.